# How can I get a mass of lasagna?

Tags: integration

A lamina occupies the part of the disk $x^2+y^2\le25$ in the first quadrant.
and lamina's density at any point is proportional to its distance from the y-axis

I want to get a mass of the lamina but I don't know how to calculate it...
I think $\rho(x,y)=x$ but i don't know the bound of x and y..

Comment: I suspect you didn't mean to write "lasagna" in your title.

Comment: @saha Please, if you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hint: use polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ with $0 \leq r \leq5$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

the density to be considered is: $\rho(r) = k \cdot r \cdot cos \theta$, with k=constant

$$M=\int_0^{pi/2} \int_0^{5}kr^2 \cos\theta\space dr d\theta$$

Comment: um.. earnestly I'm not good at polar coordinates.. Is there any method determine the θ of polar coordinates?

Comment: in this case you can also avoid them but for many problem it is an essential tool

Answer (score 0):

The density at $(x,y)$ is $kx$ for some constant $k$ (the $x$-coordinate is the distance from the $y$-axis and $k$ is the proportionality coefficient). The bounds come from the equation of the bounding circle ($x^2+y^2=25$) and from the fact that we want the first quadrant ($x\geq 0$, $y \geq 0$). Let $y$ go from $0$ to $5$ (the radius of the circle) then you get the bounds for $x$ as $0\leq x \leq \sqrt{25-y^2}$.

The mass is given by

$$\int_0^5 \int_0^{\sqrt{25-y^2}} kx \space dxdy = \frac{125k}{3}$$